# Python script to print nslookup

Tags: python, nslookup

```
import os

ipRange = []
for i in range(1, 254):
    ipRange.append('192.168.5' + '.' + str(i)) 

for e in ipRange:
    print os.system('nslookup ' + str(e))
```

This outputs the full output of nslookup for each ip - is there a way to discard the empty results and make the output look more like this?

```
192.168.5.5 testbox4
192.168.5.6 box3
192.168.5.8 hellobox
192.168.5.9 server2012
192.168.5.18 dnsbox
192.168.5.19 sallysbox
192.168.5.20 bobsbox
192.168.5.21 serverx
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use system?  This would do without system calls:

```
import socket

for i in range(0, 255):
    ipa = "130.233.192." + str(i)
    try:
        a = socket.gethostbyaddr(ipa)
        print (ipa, a[0])
    except socket.herror:
        pass
```

EDIT: change 255 to 256 if you want to query .255 as well but in class C networks this is the broadcast address and not in DNS. If you are trawling through class A or B networks, then .255 could be valid as well